# How to select an Array Index by a Slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I have another Workbook with a Pivot Table and a Slicer, which is sorting items by Year/Mounth (202101 - January 2021/ 202102 - Febuary etc...) and I have specific ranges for this Year/Mounth, like this.

```
202101 = Range (A4)
202102 = Range (B4)
202103 = Range (C4)
```

The function GetSlicerItems is returning me this value "202102"/"202103"/"202104" as string.
I want to based on that return, select the corresponding range to each mounth

I tried this, but with no Luck.

```
Dim szslicer As String
szslicer = "Slicer_Name"

Dim temprange As Range

szMounth = Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12")
szRng = Array("A4", "B4", "C4", "D4", "E4", "F4", "G4", "H4", "I4", "J4", "K4", "L4")

With ThisWorkbook

For i = 0 To szMounth()
    tempSlicer = GetSlicerItem(szslicer)
    
    If tempSlicer = "2021" & szMounth(i) Then
    tempSlicer = "2021" & szMounth(i)
    set temprange = szRng(?)
    Sheets(1).Range(temprange).Select
    End If
Next i

End With
```

Could anyone help me?

PS: I had a Function to get the slicer item as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too clear on what this code does, but something like this should be closer:

```vb
Dim szslicer As String
szslicer = Slicer_Name

szMounth = Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12")
szrng = Array("A4", "B4", "C4", "D4", "E4", "F4", "G4", "H4", "I4", "J4", "K4", "L4")

With ThisWorkbook
    tempSlicer = GetSlicerItem(szslicer)
    For i = 0 To UBound(szMounth)
        If tempSlicer = "2021" & szMounth(i) Then
            tempSlicer = "2021" & szMounth(i) 'what does this do?
            .Sheets(1).Range(szrng(i)).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim. I appreciate that. This code was a miss click haha, idk if you understand my thinking, I'm sorry for that.I want to equals the index of szRng with szMounth. Like if szMouth(1) = szRng(1), if szMounth(2) = szRng(2). And the condition to change the index of szMounth is the slicer.

Comment: I think so, but in getting Runtime error '13' on this line For i = 0 To UBound(szMounth) :(

Comment: How did you declare `i` ?  As Long ?

Comment: It's always safer to use `Long` - there's no saving using `Integer`, and `Integer` can overflow if you're using it as a row counter for example.  If you're not already using `Option Explicit` then you should turn that on.

Comment: I see. Thank you, my friend. You helped me a lot. I wish you luck on your life bro.